# XNA Rectangle overlay on an texture for Intersect collisions

Tags: c#, xna, textures

all.

We're trying to get some intersect collisions working, but the problem experience is that the Rectangle does not overlay correcting on the texture.

The texture is a 20x340 pixel image. In the class (`Net`) for the texture we have a `Rectangle` to use as the collision box (`SetCollisionBox` method). We define the following in the `Game` class (under `LoadContent()` method).

```
g_Net = new Net("Net1");
g_scene.Place(g_Net, new Vector3(8, 100, 1));
g_Net.SetCollisionBox(new Rectangle((int)g_Net.Position.X, (int)g_Net.Position.Y, 20, 340));
```

The problem we have is that the Rectangle is drawn above the texture (*the Net*) and adjusting the height does make it line up more, but then only the above is collidable with the ball object with a `g_Ball.ballRectIntersect(g_Net.netRect)`. `netRect` being a public member `Rectangle` in the `Net` class and `ballRect` being the equivalent for the `Ball` class.

So my question is how can I get the `Rectangle` overlay to properly appear over the texture so that collision are corresponds with the entire net texture? Is there better way to place this overlay?

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers.

- Sam.

Comment: Do you have an image to show what it looks like?

Comment: It would help to see what SetCollisionBox does.

Comment: `public void SetCollisionBox(Rectangle rect) { netRect = rect; }`

Comment: where `netRect` is `public Rectangle netRect` also in `Net` class.

Comment: Are we better off drawing a raw Rectangle and placing a texture on it? Thanks.

Comment: Based on my limited reading of [Drawing a Tile Based Spaceship on Screen in XNA](http://www.jgallant.com/articles/drawing_a_tile_based_spaceship_on_screen_in_xna) I think you hit it on the head.  Draw the rectangle and place the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your texture is 2D, since you said Texture and you're using a Rectangle instead of a BoundingBox.

In that case, this is very simple to answer.

To set your collision properties, here's how you do it. Let's assume position is our texture position and texture is our loaded texture.

```
Rectangle boundingRect = new Rectangle(position.X, position.Y, position.X + texture.Width, position.Y + texture.Height);
```

Also, if your game is a 2D game, you shouldn't use a Vector3 to store position unless you're forced to. Try to use a Vector2, it'll save you some memory.

Cheers!